# RPi Streaming Audio Server

Tags: audio, streaming

I'm trying to build a system similar to the following diagram:
[image]

My plan is to configure my Raspberry Pi, depicted as the Mixxx Block in the diagram, to stream audio from a file or a microphone connected to the RPi.
The stream should be sent over the internet to an Icecast server, one like listen2myradio.com, which will handle the broadcasting to multiple Listeners.

I found many tutorials on the internet using MPD and MPC connected to an Icecast server. However, all the tutorials I went through have the MPD and Icecast on one RPi, similar to the following diagram[image]

I tried to adapt the same instructions found in those tutorials, but replaced stuff like "localhost" with the ip address I got from listen2myradio.

following is how I configured my MPD:

```
audio_output {
  type            "shout"
  name            "RasPi MPD Stream"
  description     "MPD stream on Raspberry Pi"
  host            "78.126.230.18"
  port            "8129"
  mount           "/stream"
  password        "ICECAST_SOURCE_PASSWORD"
  bitrate         "128"
  format          "44100:16:2"
  encoding        "mp3"
}
```

However there was no connection to the Icecast server.
Executing the command netstat -ltpn gives:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      365/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      366/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      405/mpd
tcp6       0      0 :::6600                 :::*                    LISTEN      405/mpd
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      365/systemd-resolve
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      366/sshd
```

My question is: what does the address ":::8000" in the netstat above means?

Is there a good tutorial to build a system similar to the one described above?
I'm open to any other software other than MPD and Icecast.

Many thanx in advanced!

p.S.: I'm using Archlinux

Comment: VLC should allow you to capture the mic and stream it to your icecast server, but I'm struggling a wee bit to find an all in one tutorial. The addresses in your netstat are ports currently in use.

Comment: try to disable IPv6 via sysctl and use IPv4-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to get MPD, MPC & Icecast to work together.
What I have done, is to go one step back, by experimenting with MPD and MPC to play music locally.
Afterwards I tried again the connection to the Icecast server, and it works directly, with the same configuration I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have neither a USB mic or soundcard to hand that I can test this with. Lots of confirmed reports of everything working well though, so this should at least point the way.

[This](https://prupert.wordpress.com/2010/08/02/stream-live-audio-from-a-microphone-in-near-real-time-in-ubuntu/) post describes using VLC to capture an incoming USB mic signal on interface hw(0,0), transcode it to mpeg2 and stream it to an rtp client:

```
cvlc -vvv alsa://hw:0,0 --sout '#transcode{acodec=mp2,ab=32}:rtp{dst=192.168.1.5,port=1234,sdp=rtsp://192.168.1.5:8085/lily.sdp}'
```

[This](http://wp.voltnet.co.uk/vlc-and-icecast-streaming) post describes transcoding an m3u playlist to MP3 and streaming out to IceCast:

```
vlc -vvv c:\playlist.m3u --sout "#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:gather:std{access=shout,mux=ogg,dst=source:hackme@domain.co.uk:8000/stream2}" --sout-keep
```

So. Conflating the two to achieve capturing the mic, transcoding to stereo MP3 (mono can occasionally default to left channel only) at 128kbps/44.1kHz sampling rate we get something that looks a bit like:

```
cvlc -vvv alsa://hw:0,0 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:gather:std{access=shout,mux=ogg,dst=source:hackme@domain.co.uk:8000/stream2}' --sout-keep
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!
I'll try it out, hope it will work :)